# Object loses data after initialization

Tags: c#, winforms

I have these objects in my project:

- SchedulerList
- SchedulerListItem
- SchedulerListItemDetails

each one is a win forms control, which are used in forms of my application. The SchedulerList holds SchedulerListItems and each item can have SchedulerListItemDetails.

my code goes as follows:

```
//creating my initial list form
FrmListTesting f = new FrmListTesting();

f.Show();
```

The form has only one button that has a hard-coded parameter for testing purposes, as well as a SchedulerList control taht will hold the list items.

When the button is clicked the form does the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var control = this.Controls[1] as SchedulerList;
    var path = @"D:\Share\Countries.txt";
    var sli = new SchedulerListItem(path);
    control.AddItem(sli);
}
```

my SchedulerListItem constuctor goes as follows:

```
public SchedulerListItem(string path)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);

    this.SourcePath = path;

    this.DestinationPath = GetDestinationPath(path);
}
```

And the AddItem method is defined as:

```
public void AddItem(SchedulerListItem item)
{
    this.flPanel.Controls.Add(item);
}
```

The add item method works as intended, displays all the data that was required and displays it in the UI. The list item has a button that brings up the details form as such:

```
//the form constructor
public FrmSchedulerItemDetails(SchedulerListItem item)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.detailsControl = new SchedulerListItemDetails(item, this);
}

//control constructor
public SchedulerListItemDetails(SchedulerListItem item, Form owner)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.SourcePath = item.SourcePath;
    this.DestinationPath = item.DestinationPath;
    this.OldFormat = item.OldFormat;
    this.ExportToExcel = item.ExportToExcel;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.underlyingItem = item;
}
```

And now the problem. After the SchedulerListItemDetails constructor is called and the data "gets initialized", when i look at the data inside the object its set to default values. it seams that everything that I set after `InitializeComponent();` gets ignored.

things that i have tried:

- hard-coding the values to see if primitives get passed correctly
- settings breakpoints on every `InitializeComponent()` method to see the stack trace associated with setting to default values

none of the methods show any results... I know that if i use a form directly instead of using a control within a from i can set the values the way i want to, but I'm very confused as to why this other method with controls doesn't work.

EDIT 1:

the code for SchedulerListItemDetails:

```
public partial class SchedulerListItemDetails : UserControl
{
    public SchedulerListItemDetails(SchedulerListItem item, Form owner)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SourcePath = item.SourcePath;
        this.DestinationPath = item.DestinationPath;
        this.OldFormat = item.OldFormat;
        this.ExportToExcel = item.ExportToExcel;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.underlyingItem = item;
    }

    public SchedulerListItemDetails()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Form owner = null;

    private SchedulerListItem underlyingItem;

    public Boolean ExportToExcel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.cbxExcel.Checked;
        }
        set
        {
            this.cbxExcel.Checked = value;
        }
    }

    public Boolean OldFormat
    {
        get
        {
            return this.cbxOldFormat.Checked;
        }
        set
        {
            this.cbxOldFormat.Checked = value;
        }
    }

    public String DestinationPath
    {
        get
        {
            return this.tbxDestinationPath.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            this.tbxDestinationPath.Text = value;
        }
    }

    public String SourcePath
    {
        get
        {
            return this.tbxSourcePath.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            this.tbxSourcePath.Text = value;
        }
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.owner.Close();
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        underlyingItem.SourcePath = this.SourcePath;
        underlyingItem.DestinationPath = this.DestinationPath;
        underlyingItem.OldFormat = this.OldFormat;
        underlyingItem.ExportToExcel = this.ExportToExcel;

        btnCancel_Click(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide whole code of your SchedulerListItemDetails control?

Comment: That conclusion - *"everything that I set after InitializeComponent(); gets ignored"* is wrong. Firstly debug to confirm what *set* occurs (maybe you have another constructor which is called), then ensure what you are inspecting *correct* item. Last thing, I hope properties aren't `static` ;) You can set breakpoint in property setter to ensure what nothing happens with property after its set.

Comment: @Sinatr I have put breakpoints in my setters and after the values that i want set get set, the setter doesn't get triggered in the debugger, and yet the opened form doesn't have the data it was passed

Comment: Notice you have *parameterless constructor* for `SchedulerListItemDetails` (I am almost 100% sure if you put breakpoint there, then it will trigger). Setter should be called **once** for each `SchedulerListItemDetails`. What is `detailsControl`? Is this row called? Or do you have parameterless constructor for `FrmSchedulerItemDetails` as well? How do you show this form?

Comment: @Sinatr Yes i thought it was that too, but when i put in the break point the action happened like this: the default constructor gets triggered, because it gets called by the FrmSchedulerItemDetails InitializeComponent(). after that i call my constructor and set the property to the new value. but that just seems to be ignored. the debugger always stops in that sequence, first the default constructor, and then mine.

Comment: What do you mean that "the default constructor gets triggered" and then "I call my constructor".  Can you demonstrate how that is accomplished?  It sounds like two distinct objects are being created.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway That turned out to be the problem, i have posted an explanation below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after i got a quick course of how win forms work i figured out what the problem was.

my code that i thought was enough is:

```
public FrmSchedulerItemDetails(SchedulerListItem item)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DetailsControl = new SchedulerListItemDetails(item, this);
}

public SchedulerListItemDetails DetailsControl
{
    get 
    { 
        return this.detailsControl; 
    }
    set 
    {
        this.detailsControl = value;
    }
}
```

the this.detailsControl is the control im trying to setup, but as i have learned the correct way of replacing a component for a new one is:

```
public FrmSchedulerItemDetails(SchedulerListItem item)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DetailsControl = new SchedulerListItemDetails(item, this);
}

public SchedulerListItemDetails DetailsControl
{
    get 
    { 
        return this.detailsControl; 
    }
    set 
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(this.detailsControl);
        this.detailsControl = value;
        this.Controls.Add(this.detailsControl);
    }
}
```

Feel kinda silly now :).

Answer (score 0):

I'll make an answer, because it should help you to solve your problem.

You have default (parameterless) constructor, which *may be called* and if it is called, then your constructor with parameters **is not called**.

Proper design would be something like

```
public partial class SchedulerListItemDetails : UserControl
{
    public SchedulerListItemDetails()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public SchedulerListItemDetails(SchedulerListItem item, Form owner): this()
    {
        this.SourcePath = item.SourcePath;
        ...
    }
}
```

Notice `this()`, this ensure what parameterless constructor is called before (and `InitializeComponent()` as well, no need to duplicate it in another constructor).

---

Back to your problem. In your case it's like this

```
public partial class SchedulerListItemDetails : UserControl
{
    public SchedulerListItemDetails()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public SchedulerListItemDetails(SchedulerListItem item, Form owner)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SourcePath = item.SourcePath;
        ...
    }
}
```

**Only one constructor can be called**. So if you put breakpoint in parameterless one and it's triggered, then you have problems. Because you create somewhere `SchedulerListItemDetails` without setting it's properties (they stay default).

More likely problem is that you create `new` instance of that object (either before or after constructing proper, if your code ever construct such object) and that instance is what you inspect later.